# For an operator $L$ is it true that $(Lf)^* = Lf^*$?

Tags: calculus

If $L = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +p(x)$ the is it true to say that $(Lf)^* = Lf^*$ where $f^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of $f$ and $f$ and $p(x)$ is real (here $L$ is the Schrodinger operator).

Essentially I am unsure if $(\frac{d}{dx} f)^* = \frac{d}{dx} f^*$. Is this statement true? It is obviously true for real and constant functions, but if $f$ is still constant is this true?

Answer (score 0):

If the variable $x$ is real, yes. Then $(\frac{d}{dx}f)^*=\frac{d}{dx}f^*$. And assuming $g(x)$ is a real, also $(Lf)^* = Lf^*$